# Leaflet/CartoDB L.featureGroup.subGroup()

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I'm currently having issues getting the subgroups working properly. With the code below, I'm able to display the clusters however when I turn the layers off the clusters do not update accordingly. Additionally, when I turn on a layer the underlying points all turn on. How do I get the subgroup layers to work properly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Map</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!-- If IE use the latest rendering engine -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Set the page to the width of the device and set the zoon level -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">

    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Leaflet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/v1.0.0-beta.2.0/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/v1.0.0-beta.2.0/dist/MarkerCluster.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/v1.0.0-beta.2.0/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>

    <div id="map" style="height: 800px"></div>

    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([38.607, -97.277], 5);

        var OpenMapSurfer_Grayscale = L.tileLayer('http://korona.geog.uni-heidelberg.de/tiles/roadsg/x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',
            {
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: 'Imagery from <a href="http://giscience.uni-hd.de/">' +
            'GIScience Research Group @ University of Heidelberg</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; ' +
            '<a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        }).addTo(map);

        //attributes for basemap credit (lower right hand corner annotation)
        var streetsAttr = 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>';
        var aerialAttr = 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community';
        var artsyfartsyAttr = 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>';

        //crete variables for the base map layer switcher
        var streets = L.tileLayer('http://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            id: 'MapID',
            attribution: streetsAttr
          }),
          aerial = L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
            id: 'MapID',
            attribution: aerialAttr
          }),
          artsyfartsy = L.tileLayer('http://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            id: 'MapID',
            attribution: artsyfartsyAttr
          });

        //create baseMaps variable to store basemap layer switcher
        var baseMaps = {
          "Streets": streets,
          "Aerial": aerial,
          "ArtsyFartsy": artsyfartsy
        };
        var masClusGroup = new L.markerClusterGroup().addTo(map);

        var efuSub = L.featureGroup.subGroup(masClusGroup).addTo(map);
        var f1Sub = L.featureGroup.subGroup(masClusGroup).addTo(map);
        var f2Sub = L.featureGroup.subGroup(masClusGroup).addTo(map);

        var sqlEFU = "https://kmitch24.carto.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q=SELECT * FROM tornadodata_beginningpoint where tor_f_scal = 'EFU'";
        var sqlF1 = "https://kmitch24.carto.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q=SELECT * FROM tornadodata_beginningpoint where tor_f_scal = 'F1'";
        var sqlF2 = "https://kmitch24.carto.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q=SELECT * FROM tornadodata_beginningpoint where tor_f_scal = 'F2'";

        $.getJSON(sqlEFU, function(cartodbdata) {
            geojsonlayer= L.geoJson(cartodbdata, {
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    layer.bindPopup("F-Scale: " + feature.properties.tor_f_scal + "<br>" +
                        "Deaths: " + feature.properties.deaths_dir + "<br>" +
                        "Damage: " + feature.properties.damage_pro + '');
                }
            }).addTo(efuSub);
         });
        $.getJSON(sqlF1, function(cartodbdata) {
            geojsonlayer= L.geoJson(cartodbdata, {
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    layer.bindPopup("F-Scale: " + feature.properties.tor_f_scal + "<br>" +
                        "Deaths: " + feature.properties.deaths_dir + "<br>" +
                        "Damage: " + feature.properties.damage_pro + '');
                }
            }).addTo(f1Sub);
         });

        $.getJSON(sqlF2, function(cartodbdata) {
            geojsonlayer= L.geoJson(cartodbdata, {
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    layer.bindPopup("F-Scale: " + feature.properties.tor_f_scal + "<br>" +
                        "Deaths: " + feature.properties.deaths_dir + "<br>" +
                        "Damage: " + feature.properties.damage_pro + '');
                }
            }).addTo(f2Sub);
         });

        //Tornado Path.
        var tPath = new L.layerGroup([]);
        var path = "https://kmitch24.carto.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q=SELECT * FROM tornadodata_path";

        $.getJSON(path, function(cartodbdata) {
            geojsonlayer= L.geoJson(cartodbdata, {
            }).addTo(tPath);
         });

        var overLayMap = {
            "EFU": efuSub,
            "F1": f1Sub,
            "F2": f2Sub,
            "Tornado Path": tPath
        };

        L.control.layers(baseMaps, overLayMap).addTo(map);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Looks like you should simply use [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) version 1.0.0 instead of 1.0.0-beta.2.0

Version 1.0.0 (which is the most recent as of writing) includes [PR#624](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/pull/624) which brings the management of nested Layer Groups, which is very probably your case.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/iA9f3jd5Ov0Ln46Id7FW?p=preview

---

Original answer:

Not sure exactly why the subgroup seems to be "disconnected" from the parent Marker Cluster group… :-S

[Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup) is supposed to work correctly with intermediate Layer Groups, as in your case with the GeoJSON group that is used to build Leaflet layers from your GeoJSON data retrieved by jQuery AJAX. Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0OlNGdBE47AnsL4seLK?p=preview

A workaround is to get rid of that intermediate group and to add the individual layers directly into the appropriate subgroup:

```js
$.getJSON(sqlEFU, function(cartodbdata) {
    geojsonlayer= L.geoJson(cartodbdata, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup("some text").addTo(efuSub); // Add individual layers
        }
    })/*.addTo(efuSub)*/; // No longer add the intermediate GeoJSON group.
 });
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/eMzG9RkoV7fsNODotiSt?p=preview

If you can build a minimal test case that reproduces your issue, it would be easier to pinpoint the reason for your code not working.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at the code, I've after reviewing the demo you provided I've been able to fix and get everything working for all addition features needed.